# source code of npm 'events' (v1.0.0) module confused me

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

sourcecode [here](https://github.com/Gozala/events/blob/v1.0.0/events.js)

```
function EventEmitter() {
  this._events = this._events || {};
  this._maxListeners = this._maxListeners || undefined;
}
```

I know this is a constructor, and every time an instance created, the 2 line code inside constructor execute once, my question is that:

why `this._events = this._events || {}`;

i think `this._events = {};` is enough

same puzzle about `_maxListeners`

and what makes me more puzzled is the following:

```
EventEmitter.prototype._events = undefined;
EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = undefined;
```

why we have to set property to `undefined`